# Memory keep rising during Load Test

Tags: tomcat, memory-leaks, jmeter

We are using Jersey, Spring, hibernate to develop a RESTful server. Running a load test locally using JMeter tool and using javamelody to monitor the CPU and memory usage.

After few days, I found that the memory keep rising but seem never releasing back. I generated heap dump from javamelody and using Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT) to check any memory leak but the result is no memory leak found.

[image]

I have no idea to figure out the reason of memory keep rising.
Any experienced person knows the reason?

My server environments are Tomcat 9 and MySQL Database.

Below is the Tomcat Java Options

-Xms1024m

-Xmx4096m

-XX:NewSize=512m

-XX:MaxNewSize=2560m

-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=250

-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

-XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary

-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

-XX:PermSize=300m

-XX:MaxPermSize=300m

-Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=43200

Thanks!

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 3 days UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck My server have  32GB RAM, i7 CPU and 256GB SSD. During my load test, the CPU usage is around ~5% only. There are a lot of values in MySQL global variable and status. I think this is difficult to show here. Do you have any variable you needed?

Comment: Please post on pastebin.com and share the links to avoid storage limits here on SO. This is a complimentary website for TEXT files to be shared.

Answer (score 0):

JVM has a lazy approach to garbage collection. It won't try to free up the memory until it gets close to `xmx` value. Also it's typically a good practise to use the same value for `xmx` and `xms` which should give you better performance as GC occur more frequently but will have to work less hard. Try and set xmx and xms both to 4G and see how it behaves.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try this and re-run the load test again!